# difference between these Time complexity

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

what is difference between O(N Log^2N) and O(N LogLogN) time complexity?

I can't understand whats the difference?

Comment: The first is the same as *O(n (log n)^2)* or *O(n * log n * log n). The second is *O(n log(log(n)))*. (Notational convention of logarithms can be confusing, I think it's a valid question.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one means squaring the log of n. The second means taking the log of the log of n, i.e.

```
O( n * log(n) * log(n) )
```

vs.

```
O( n * log(log(n)) )
```